# Preload image in dynamically added PivotItem

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm using a Pivot to display a dynamic amount of pivot items. The following code is a simplified version of what I'm doing.

```
//.xaml
<Pivot Name="PivotImages">
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Name="ImageFull" Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>

//.xaml.cs
private readonly ObservableCollection<PhotoPageViewModel> _photoPageViewModelList = new ObservableCollection<PhotoPageViewModel>();
PivotImages.ItemsSource = _photoPageViewModelList;

//PhotoPageViewModel.cs
private string _photoUrl;
public string PhotoUrl
{
    get { return _photoUrl; }
    set
    {
        _photoUrl = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PhotoUrl");
    }
}
```

I add new items with

```
_photoPageViewModelList.Add(new PhotoPageViewModel());
```

where `PhotoUrl` is initialized in the constructor. The model seems to work as desired. Problem is that `ImageFull` loads the image from the web when the new pivot item is selected.

> What i would like to achieve is that the image loads when the new pivot item is added and not when it's the selected pivot item. So when you swipe to the next pivot item, you should already see the loaded image.
>
> Edit: I realized that i might be using the wrong Element to solve my problem. A Pivot only shows the new Item when the swipe animation is completed. What i would like to have, is a visible pivot item right next to the current one. Just like in the Photo App, where you can see the next photo as soon as you start swiping left or right.

Comment: Use an ImageSource instead of an URL string as view model property? You may then load the image into a BitmapImage in the PhotoPageViewModel constructor.

Comment: I think using an ImageSource solves the loading Problem. But i realized that i might be using the wrong Element to solve my problem. A Pivot only shows the new Item when the swipe animation is completed. What i would like to have, is a visible pivot item right next to the current one. Just like in the Photo App, where you can see the next photo as soon as you start swiping left or right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot is not the element you want to use. 
You should use a [Flipview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview.aspx) instead.